# Using 2 wifi adapters to create a hotspot

Tags: wireless, network-bridge

I'm trying to create a wifi hotspot with an external wifi apdater. What I have is an onboard wifi (wlan0) that is connected to the internet and an external one (wlan1). What I'm trying to do is bridge? them together so I can create a wifi hotspot. Any point in the right direction would be appreciated.